# javascript array only first character displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor

I'm currently working on a ckeditor plugin, the selectbox gets its data from a DB and I can only get the first character to appear in the selectbox.

get_pages.php

```
$query = selectQuery('
    SELECT title, pageID
    FROM  `page_info` 
    WHERE partnerID =?',array($partnerId));
$test = '';
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
$test .= $value['title'].",";
}
```

**Plugin.js**

```
var pages = $.post(
        "/action/ac_select_pages.php",
        { pid: "1" },
        function(data) {
            return (data);         
    }
);

pages = pages.responseText.split(',');
```

my variable:

```
pages: Array[31]  
    0: "Home"  
    1: "Control Panel"  
    2: "24/7 Support"  
    3: "Script / Databases"  
    4: "Last Announcment"  
    5: "E-mail: No Limit"  
    6: "Webmail & Push Mail"
```

and so on..

what I do to make my selectbox:

```
{
    type : 'select',
    id : 'moreinfo',
    label : 'Meerinfo Link',
    style : 'width:300px;',
    items : pages ,
    setup : function( element )
    {
    this.setValue( element.getAttribute( "moreinfo" ) );
    },
    commit : function( element )
    {
    var id = this.getValue();
    // If the field is non-empty, use its value to set the element's id attribute.
    if ( id )
    element.setAttribute( 'moreinfo', id );
    // If on editing the value was removed by the user, the id attribute needs to be removed.
    // http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.element.html#removeAttribute
    else if ( !this.insertMode )
        element.removeAttribute( 'moreinfo' );
    }
}
```

As you can see I simply put the array in the items , but it shows only the first character
[image: Dialog Block]

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you provide more code

Comment: How are generating that dropdown?  You're probably treating the string like an array.

Comment: @clph3r more info as requested.
@RocketHazmat get from db like this `page1,page2,page3`
split to make array
set array as items

so till i make the pages array it is working, but when i say `items : pages` it only gets the first character. it sees the second character as the option value :S

Comment: Can you expand on the *"what I do to make my selectbox:"* part? All you have is an object; it would be helpful to see the full command.

Comment: try to put local data in the select. `var pages = [{0: 'Home', 1: 'Control Panel', ...}];`. If your select works as you expected then i suppose that is a server side problem. If it is a server side problem try to return a json prom your php with the data ready to use in your select

Comment: @AymanSafadi I don't understand your question. this is an element of the content of a ckeditor dialog. the settings of the element are all there.

`@pbaris` I tryed that :) and it works, but as the pages are constantly added and deleted i can't hard code the pages in the select.

Answer (score 1):

So, to summarize...

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) *Splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.*

So, presumably your `pages.responseText` looks like this:

```
Home,Control Panel,24/7 Support,Script / Databases,Last Announcment,E-mail: No Limit,Webmail & Push Mail
```

Which means that after doing `pages = pages.responseText.split(',');`, `pages` looks like this (an array):

```
["Home", "Control Panel", "24/7 Support", "Script / Databases", "Last Announcment", "E-mail: No Limit", "Webmail & Push Mail"]
```

According to your [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939193/javascript-array-only-first-character-displayed#comment-20966890), this works:

```
var pages = [{0: 'Home', 1: 'Control Panel', ...}];
```

As you can see (an array with multiple values):

```
["Home", "Control Panel", ...]
```

is **not** the same as (an array with one object with several properties):

```
[{0: 'Home', 1: 'Control Panel', ...}]
```

---

If all of this is still true, something like this should work:

```
var pagesObject = {};
for (var i=0, max=pages.length; i<max; i += 1) {
  pagesObject[i] = pages[i];
}

var correctPages = [ pagesObject ];
```

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/ikazes/1/edit

Comment: i can't access the code from home so I will try this tomorrow. thx in advance for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the for loop of **Ayman Sadadi** I got it finally right:)

```
// page1, 1,00,page2, 12,00,page3, 23 \\
pages = pages.responseText.split(',00,');
// ["page1, 1","page2, 12","page3, 23"] \\
var a = [];
a[0] = '';
for (var b = 0; b < pages.length; b++) {
    var c = pages[b].split(', ');
    var pageName = c[0];
    var pageId = c[1];
    a[b] = [ pageName, c ];
};
```

a is now:

```
a: Array[31]
  0: Array[2]
    0: "Home"
    1: Array[2]
      0: "Home"
      1: "1"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
 1: Array[2]
    0: "Control Panel"
    1: Array[2]
      0: "Control Panel"
      1: "152"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

this is the same as the required `[['Home']['Control Panel']]`.
If I use that as my items it works correctly.

previous conversation:

> try to put local data in the select. var pages = [{0: 'Home', 1: 'Control Panel', ...}];. ...
>
> ---
>
> I tryed that :) and it works, but as the pages are constantly added and deleted i can't hard code the pages in the select
>
> ---
>
> Ayman Safadi: According to your previous comment, this works...

Only if I hard code it like `[['home']['Control Panel']]` it works. `[{0: 'Home', 1: 'Control Panel', ...}]`  did not work. I'm sorry to be a little unclear about what I meant.

Thank you for helping me with my problem.
**Credits go to Ayman Safadi / pbaris :)**